# How to show tick marks for Discrete Slider?

Tags: android, material-design, seekbar, material-components-android, android-slider

[image]

I'm trying to style a seekbar/slider like the one labeled **Discrete Slider - Click** (that has the little tick mark indicators) in the [Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#sliders-continuous-slider). I can't figure out the magical incantation to have the tickmarks show up, does anyone know how to do this?

I have a seekbar with 5 positions (0-4)

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="4" />
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add tick marks with the style attribute:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10"
    />
```

Or add them manually by setting the tickMark drawable:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10"
    android:tickMark="@drawable/tickmark"
    />
```

tickmark.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="4dp"
          android:height="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Ahh looks like this was recently added in the 24.x.x support lib (does not appear to be available in 23.4.0)

Comment: @NameSpace I'm not getting ticker indicator on seekbar, Can you please help me ?

Comment: @NameSpace how does the seek bar know the step size to place the tickmark

Comment: It knows it from the "max" value. When max is 10, it will divide the SeekBar into 10 segments, and put a tickmark between each.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use the [**`Slider`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md#discrete-slider) in the Material Components Library.
The tick marks are displayed by default in the discrete sliders.

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="10"
        android:stepSize="1"
        .../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use **com.google.android.material.slider.Slider**

```
app:tickVisible="true" // false
```